# Flask-Admin SQLAlchemy: How to set an attribute value according to another with a python function?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Python 3.6.5, Flask 1.0.2. I want to define an attribute of a db Model according to another with a python function, like this:

```
def define_category(age):
    if age < 12:
        return 'child'
    elif age < 20:
        return 'teen'
    else:
        return 'adult'

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    category = define_category(age)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I've tried with [hybrid attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) and it doesn't appear to work with different types of data.

Comment: `def set_age(self, value): ... user.set_age(12)`